# browser caching disrupting HTML Select List Ajax filtering: triggered by the onchange event

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, xhtml, asp-classic

I have HTML select list boxes that allow users to search for items. I also have an a simple Ajax implementation that enforces filtering when users select items - triggered by the *select* element's onchange event firing when options are clicked.

**App. logic**: user selects items and hits submit -> goes to the search results page.

My problem is when a user navigates back [by browser back button] from my Search Results Page to the select list boxes, the selections are retained but filtering is somehow lost. I think this might be due to browser caching falling apart?

eg. Look of my Searh Page by default.

**Search for food Food Products by Ingredients**

1. INGREDIENT

   - **All Ingredients***
   - Bread
   - Cheese
2. INGREDIENT TYPES

   - **All Ingredient types***
   - Cheddar Cheese
   - White bun
   - White Cheese
   - Wholemeal bun

By default the options "*All Ingredients*" and "*All Ingredient Types*" are selected by default when the search page loads the search page.

*An example of how the simple filter works and the problem scenario in hitting the browser back button.*

Scenario: a user then selects bread and the Ajax call filters the second list to only bread items. A user then selects white bun and hits  a search  button

1. INGREDIENT

   - All Ingredients*
   - **Bread**
   - Cheese
2. INGREDIENT TYPES

   - All Ingredient types*
   - **White bun**
   - Wholemeal bun

The user then views the search results which is correct, but on *navigating back by hitting the browser back button*, this is the view presented. Selections are correct and intact however filtering falls apart.

1. INGREDIENT

   - All Ingredients*
   - **Bread**
   - Cheese
2. INGREDIENT TYPES

   - All Ingredient types*
   - Cheddar Cheese
   - **White bun**
   - White Cheese
   - Wholemeal bun

I'm using xmlHTTP = new XMLHttpRequest() form my ajax implementation.

Questions:
I'd appreciate answers on:

- what's causing this to occur?
- How I can resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing code, I suspect that your filtering code only runs when the select event fires.  Clicking the "back" button reloads the page including the previous form element values/selections, but the select event doesn't fire.

Your code needs to run the filtering logic both after the page loads and when the select event is fired.